# are there any applications/extensions to aid faster resizing and movement of windows in Vista/XP?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

I like a number of features of Linux window management that I don't know a way to emulate on Windows

- Window resizing / moving with [alt] and right/middle mouse buttons
- Horizontal and vertical maximization, which can be bound to keyboard shortcuts (LXDE, KDE)
- Window packing (move left/right/up/down to the nearest border or screen edge), which can also be bound to keyboard shortcuts

I cannot find anything to do all of this in Windows. Win7 seemed to have a partial solution of adding keyboard bindings for left/right/maximize.

I have heard tweakui can do the first one, but it doesn't seem to be well supported in Vista. I also want downloads I can trust; please tell me if you've actually used it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altdrag (http://code.google.com/p/altdrag/) is what I use for the first one. Works very well; only thing I can think of is that it doesn't Aero Snap if you Alt+Rightdrag a window to the edge.

Answer (score 1):

[WindowSpace](http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html) can definitely do 2 and 3, but I'm not sure about #1.  It's not free, but it is awesome, and something I use every day.